# failure to find didutil:did:jar:1.0.1

Tags: maven, maven-2, aem

I have added the following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
        <artifactId>cq-wcm-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.10</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>
        <artifactId>cq-xssprotection</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But i am getting the following error while the mvn clean install command.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project platform.media: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.abc:platform.media:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
>
> Failure to find **didutil:did:jar:1.0.1** in http://repo.adobe.com/archiva/repository/day-central was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of day-external-central has elapsed or updates are forced

Please help.

Regards,
Vaibhav Chaturvedi

Answer (score 1):

Try cq-wcm-core version **5.5.0** instead of 5.4.x

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
  <artifactId>cq-wcm-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :).

If Maven get the correct diagnostic, you should try the update option (-U)

```
mvn clean install -U
```

This will force the download.

*Additional question :*

Are you sure you provided the good credentials ?

It seems that this repo (http://repo.adobe.com/archiva/repository/day-central) redirect to http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public (take a look, it's browsable), but this repo doesn't exist (or public does not contain anything).

***EDIT*** :
Here the correction repository : 
http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/

Notice that only the solution has changed archiva --> nexus :)

And all your artifacts seems to be here : http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/day/cq/wcm/cq-content/

Strangegly, it's now accessible.

Good Luck.

Comment: Its still not working .. the command tried to download it from all the repository paths .. but none downloaded this .. Can you please suggest the repository path in which this dependency can be found..

Comment: No luck ..... I have made changes as you suggested .. but it tries to download did:jar:1.0.1 but is not able to do that ... here's the output.
[WARNING] The POM for didutil:did:jar:1.0.1 is missing, no dependency informatio
n available
Downloading: http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/didutil/did/1.0.1/did-1.0.1.jar
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/central-sync/didutil/
did/1.0.1/did-1.0.1.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/didutil/did/1.0.1/did-1.0.1.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/didutil/did/1.0.1/did-1.0.1.jar
and then the same error

Comment: You're right, I didn't follow the good library. Indeed, it seems that you are not the only one : http://forums.adobe.com/message/4566085. I don't know why, but it seems do disapear from this Repo. I don't even know what this library is, nor where to find it sorry.